# retrieving images from server using ajax, jQuery. code not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using following jquery code to retrieve images from a folder on server.

```
 var dir = "/images";
var fileextension=".jpg";
  $.ajax({
        url: dir,
        success: function (data) {

            $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
                var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///","");               
                $("body").append($("<img src=" + dir + filename + "></img>"));
            });
        }
    });
```

I get an error "Failed to load resource file:///D:/images"
Image folder is in the same path where my index.html is located.
Any idea what is wrong with this code. I am new with ajax, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you need to specify the url to the images `http://localhost/images/image.jpg` or something similar or try to remove the first slash in `var dir = "/images";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serve the file using a web server, for example xampp or IIS or something similar. Otherwise your code will try to read directly from the filesystem and it'll be blocked by the browser.

Check the URL in your address bar when you load your index.html file, does it start with file:///, then you need to set up a development web server on your computer.

Comment: I am using tomcat now and I am getting this error  GET http://localhost:8080/images/ 404 (Not Found)
send
b.extend.ajax 
(anonymous function)

Comment: What do you see if you go to that page in your browser? It looks like for your code to work that URL must return an HTML page with links to  all the images in the directory.

Comment: It gives nothing. Yes it should give the list of all the images but there is no output with error  localhost:8080/images 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cannot load client machine files using ajax as it poses security risk. Imagine the problem when javascript steals files on your local machine. You have to deploy it on a web server and use `http` or `https` protocol to retrieve files on the same domain.